# how to avoid useEffect() race condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm very familiar with ReactJS but just started to embrace Hooks.

What's difficult to me is sometimes how to wrap imperative APIs to hooks. I have the feeling that sometimes I'm using the wrong approach.

For example, take this greatly simplified example from a real-world application. Assume there is a global state API (that can't be changed):

- `server.getState(name)` returns the last known state (let's say, it's a string) in a synchronous manner
- `server.on(name, callback)` registers an event handler for changes of that state
- `server.off(name, callback)` de-registers that event handler

I want to create a custom hook `useServerState(name, defaultValue)` that returns a live value of that state.

My implementation would look like this:

```js
function useServerState(name, defaultValue) {

  const [ curState, setCurState ] = useState(() => server.getState(name) || defaultValue);

  useEffect(
    () => {

      const evHandler = payload => setCurState(payload);

      // register on mount:
      server.on(name, evHandler);

      // de-register on unmount:
      return () => server.off(name, evHandler);

    },
    [ name ]
  );

  return curState;

}
```

Usage:

```
function SomeComponent() {

  const temperature = useServerState("temp_outside", "unknown");

  return <div>
    Current temperature: {temperature} degrees
  </div>;

}
```

## The problem

This works, but the problem is that `useEffect()` seems to invoke the function *asynchronously*. There is some delay until my `useEffect()` handler is run, like **50 ms** or so. During that time **my hook is blind for new events** that might come in in the meantime (since the event handler is not registered yet), which means that the hook might return an old state even if it has been updated.

## A (inelegant) workaround

I can work around the problem by calling `getState()` again *inside the useEffect() handler* (with other words, on "mount"):

```js
function useServerState(name, defaultValue) {

  const getInitialState = () => server.getState(name) || defaultValue;
  const [ curState, setCurState ] = useState(getInitialState);

  useEffect(
    () => {

      const evHandler = payload => setCurState(payload);

      // register on mount:
      server.on(name, evHandler);

// ----->
      // anti race condition hack:
      const nv = getInitialState();
      
      if (nv !== curState)
        setCurState(nv);
// <-----

      // de-register on unmount:
      return () => server.off(name, evHandler);

    },
    [ name ]
  );

  return curState;

}
```

## Another (bad) workaround

Another solution could be to always use a fixed start value and read the current state on mount only:

```js
function useServerState(name, defaultValue) {

  const [ curState, setCurState ] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {

      const evHandler = payload => setCurState(payload);

      // register on mount:
      server.on(name, evHandler);

      // set initial state:
      setCurState(server.getState(name) || defaultValue);

      // de-register on unmount:
      return () => server.off(name, evHandler);

    },
    [ name ]
  );

  return curState;

}
```

The downside of this solution is that it will always cause **two renders**: one with `null` and then another one with the actual state. This is not desired.

## How to improve?

The workarounds seem awkward to me and make me wonder if there is a better way to do this that does not involve a workaround. I would expect that the React team has thought about such situations. What am I missing?

Comment: The first (simple) solution not only suffers from a delay but will also not update the state according to the new name (reset the state) when `name` changes. Your "inelegant" solutions seems to be quite reasonable if you ask me. The only question would be how to implement the equality check.

Comment: Agreed, I missed the fact that the "inelegant" solution also takes care name changes. Seen that way the solution appears less hacky.

Comment: Depending on what the server state actually is it may not even be required to do an extra equality check as [react does that for you already](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update). Calling the setter of `useState` with the same value will not trigger a re-render. However if it's an object you need to implement an equality check yourself as react compares them by reference.

Comment: I had missed that detail, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your original code comments don't reflect the code logic, I believe fixing it will be enough:

```
function useServerState(name, defaultValue) {
  const [currState, setCurState] = useState(null);

  // Register on MOUNT
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currState) {
      const currServerState = server.getState(name) || defaultValue;
      setCurrState(currServerState);
    }
  }, [name]);

  // Handle name change
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!server.getState(name)) {
      server.on(name, setCurState);
    }
    return () => server.off(name, setCurState);
  }, [name]);

  return currState;
}
```

Comment: About the "50ms problem", without a reproducible example can't elaborate more, if you add such example in a codesanbox, we can talk about how to reduce this time, if it possible.

Comment: That solution would as well suffer from rendering twice on mount, once with `null` and once with the actual state which OP called "not desired".

Comment: I think its "desired" because server.on is async you should have some `loading` indicator (like `null`), also its the default behaviour on every async library, the "A (inelegant) workaround" is good enough for the "no null" issue as you mentioned

Comment: Yes you could of course work around that by showing a loading indicator. It's up to OP the decide if that works for him. Could you explain the benefit of the first effect to me? It seems as if it subscribes to an event without ever unsubscribing and it passes the server state to `on()` rather than the name. I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: Yes you are right it doesnt make sense, made some changes

Comment: Could you please explain why you use two `useEffect()` here? As for the two renders / loading indicator: no, that's not desired, as indicated in the OP. It's counterproductive to have a "loading" state since that's **not** a limitation of the imperative API. Maybe I wasn't clear, by my fictive `server.getState()` function provides *synchronous* access to the data in any moment, thus there is no "loading".

Comment: So in this case option A is a possible hook implementation, there is no "React workaround it", only if you go for concurrent mode which is not officially released